# springfox 2.2.2 no api-docs generated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, springfox

I am working on intergrating Springfox 2.2.2 into my Spring MVC project but there are no api-docs generated as I suposse should be. Below some information concerning my configuration.

I have provided following dependencies (together with additional libraries as fasterxml, webjars, correct versions of spring are used etc.)

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The Springfox is configured as follows:

```
    package com.exemplarypackage.config;
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.exemplarypackage.controller")
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "My Project's REST API", 
                "This is a description of your API.", 
                "API TOS",
                "url",
                "me@wherever.com", 
                "API License", 
                "API License URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    }
```

The exemplary controller is presented below:

```
package com.exemplarypackage.controller;
@Api(value = "test class for springfox")
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns test details")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval", response = Test.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Test does not exist"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")}
    )
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("TEST");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

With the above settings, when I executed the url: localserver:8080/myApp/swagger-ui there was almost nothing to display but there was no error message.

Then, I added to the src/main/resources/META-INF the content that I found in spring-fox-swagger-ui-2.2.2.jar (I unzipped it and pasted to given folder). Now, when I go to localserver:8080/myApp/swagger-ui all green graphics are displayed but no api docs. I noticed in server logs that swagger-ui looks for swagger-resources endpoints but it gets 404 then. When I go through the server logs, I saw that no such endpoints have been created as: swagger-resources, v2/api-docs etc. However, I noticed that the classes are filtered for swagger annotations... There is a springfox.js file in META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui folder where the swagger-resorces endpoint is contained - maybe it should be switched to different name?

I have no idea how to make it work... Should I declare somehow those endpoints or should they be automatatically created? Maybe I am just missing somthing small but I am fighting with the problem for the last days and can't figure out what else should be configured to make it work.

Comment: what do you get when you navigate to `localserver:8080/myApp/v2/api-docs`?

Comment: What does your servlet configuration look like?

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to fix the problem with help of @zubactick.
Currently, I have separate config classes for springfox and mvc. So, my springfox config is like this:

```
package com.myPackage.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{


    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .groupName("test")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "My Project's REST API", 
                "This is a description of your API.", 
                "API TOS",
                "url",
                "me@wherever.com", 
                "API License", 
                "API License URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }

}
```

And my MVC config is like this:

```
package com.myPackage.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({SwaggerConfig.class})
@ComponentScan("com.myPackage.controller")
public class WebSpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver configureViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolve = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolve.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolve.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolve;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Moreover, the following is specified in web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myPackage.config.WebSpringConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

The controller can be the same as provided in the question, however with the above swagger config, all my controllers in declared package are scanned and documented by swagger.

Comment: Thanks, this just helped me figure out that the trick is using @Import({SwaggerConfig.class}), as @ComponentScan({"com.myPackage.controller", "com.myPackage.config"}), or @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.myPackage.config") does not work for springfox.

Answer (score 0):

@gromajus, could you please try to use `@RestController` annotation instead of `@Controller` one in your exemplary controller class?

Comment: It didn't help - I changed `@Controller` with `@RestController` but nothing changed :/

Comment: @gromajus, also I see you try to get `swagger-ui` instead of `swagger-ui.html` but as @Dilip Krishnan mentioned you should get some json on `api-docs` endpoint. Does your application build without any warnings and be deployed without warning and errors?

Comment: @gromajus, I faced to same and more issues with springfox recently. I'm not an experienced gut in it. But I see some differencies between my config and your one in addition to controller annotation. They are: I have class for MVC config and for Swagger config instead of single configuration class in your example, `@Configuration` annotation I have the last one, I do not use `@Api` because I read somewhere (perhaps in java doc) that it is deprecated, also I see some errors during my googling with imported packages. Could you please provide your `import` statements (`@Api` from springfox pckg)?

Comment: I use swagger-ui.html :) There are no warnings and no errors. But there is also no api-docs (v2/api-docs) endpoint available:/ Concerning my springfox imports in Controller class, they are as follows: `import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse; `

Comment: The thing that worries me is that I see in the server logs that there is actually two runs of mapping my endpoints. In the first I see among others: /v2/api-docs, /swagger-resources, /configuration/security, /configuration/ui, /swagger-ui.html, /webjars/**, /resources/** . But in the second run, there are only the three last that I explicitly declared in the swagger config class. I am wondering why the second run is executed? Also, can you @zubactik share your config and controller classes?

Comment: @gromajus, It's too long. Please send me ping email to mail@andrey-belyaevskiy.ru and I will share my classes.